# NullPointerException - Fragment Issues

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I have unexpectedly received the following NullPointer Exception error while trying to run the application.

```
09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 3731
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731): java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment2$5.done(Fragment2.java:410)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:917)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    09-22 18:30:49.053: E/AndroidRuntime(3731):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My line 410 is as follow:

```
 mUserActivityTitleNameRetrieved2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tactivityname2);
```

If you need any clarification, let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: probably means that the results of getActivity() is returning null

Comment: it seems that getActivity() is returning null.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. would using getView be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `getActivity()` is returning `null`. You give no context for line 410, but I suspect that it is in a method that is being executed before `onAttach()` after `onDetach()` has been called for the fragment. Check out the docs on [handling the fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) lifecycle for more info about when you can rely on `getActivity()` to return a non-`null` value.

Note that if you want to access the activity's view hierarchy, you should not execute your line 410 until `onActivityCreated()` has been called.

**EDIT** It appears from the stack trace that line 410 is being executed during a call to a call-back `Runnable` after some sort of parse operation has completed. My guess is that the parsing is being done in a background thread and when it is done it posts a `Runnable` to be executed on the event (UI) thread. If so, then this `Runnable` will be executed as soon as it is encountered, regardless of what has or has not happened in the fragment lifecycle. In particular, there's nothing to stop the parsing from completing and the `Runnable` being executed before `onActivityCreated()` (or even `onAttach()`) has been called.

If this is the case, then you need some sort of mechanism to schedule things to happen at the right time. One possibility is to set a flag in the fragment when `onActivityCreated` is called. Then arrange for the call-back to be run only if the flag is set; if it is not set, then stash the `Runnable` in a variable inside the fragment. Then go back and modify `onActivityCreated` to check whether there is a stashed `Runnable` when it sets the flag. This is kind of cumbersome, but I've faced this kind of problem and this is the best solution I've found.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Would using getView instead of getActivity be better?

Comment: @user3907211 - The same principle applies. You should not call `getView()` until after `onCreateView()` has returned. Note that according to the docs, `onCreateView()` is not called until after `onAttach()` has returned. We can provide more help if you explain when this code is executing in the lifecycle of the fragment.

Comment: In this case it is being called under onActivityCreated, which comes before onCreateView, so should move onActivitycreate after oncreateview?

Comment: @user3907211 - `onActivityCreated` is called _after_ `onCreateView`. It looks from the stack trace that this is being called as part of call-back processing from some sort of parsing operation, perhaps on a separate thread from the event thread. If so, the timing of the parsing and the fragment lifecycle is indeterminate. You may need to use some internal flags to ensure that interaction with the UI elements only takes place after they are fully set up.

Comment: I am using a back-end system called Parse, and I do not think it supports Multithreading. I am new to android and not too familiar with internal flags, hence if you could provide any type of guidance, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user3907211 - I just edited my answer to sketch out what I have in mind. The solution isn't really Android-specific; it just has to do with providing some sort of handshaking in a multithreaded context.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if getActivity() returns null before calling findViewById() on it. Otherwise you will get a NullPointerException at runtime.